# loop to search a file in different directories

Tags: java, file, automation, directory

How can you search for a file in 3 different directories using a loop in Java?

I.e. assume we have a file called `FileExample` sitting in `FolderA` and we have 3 different possibilities the file might end up to when leaving `FolderA` which are:

1. DirectoryA1
2. DirectoryA2
3. DirectoryA3

for this example lets say the `FileExample` is sitting in `DirectoryA3` so therefore we need to loop to check `DirectoryA1`, `DirectoryA2`, and `DirectoryA3` for 60 seconds.

Once the loop finds `FileExample` in `DirectoryA3` we print message "file found in DirectoryA3"

Comment: Just try opening the file in each of those locations and checking if the open succeeded. What do you mean by "loop to check ... for 60 seconds"?  Do you mean that you should sleep for 60 seconds, then run the check, go back to sleep for 60 seconds, etc.?

Comment: Could you please specify your goal precisely. Do you want to find a file in 3 directories or do you want to check 3 directories until a specific file is added?

Comment: I need to check where the file will be sitting in out of those 3 different directories hence i said loop for 60 seconds to repeat the procedure until the file is dropped into one of those 3 directories.

Comment: Try taking a list of directory path and loop the list of directories and list all the files sitting in the directory. If you find your file then break the loop there else just make the thread sleep for 60 secs and run the loop again. Print which ever directory you find the file

Comment: There will be no files available in "FolderA"  except "FileExample" and once "FolderA" is empty then "FileExample" MUST be in one of the 3 directories (DirectoryA1, DirectoryA2, and DirectoryA3) which in this example I am manually dragging and dropping it to "DirectoryA3" when loop is looping. I do not want to list all files in any folder or any Directories as it will be only one file leaves "FolderA" into a Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like it:

```
public void listFiles(String directoryName, ArrayList<File> files) {
File directory = new File(directoryName);

// get all files from directory
File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
for (File file : fList) {
   // verify if file
    if (file.isFile()) {
        files.add(file);
    // verify if directory 
    } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
        listFiles(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Basically I will drag "FileExample" and drop into "DirectoryA3" manually while the loop is looping. Once the "FileExample" is found in  "DirectoryA3"  we print message "file found in DirectoryA3". does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, you can define your implementation depending on your requirements.